# How can I remove a doubled section of a string?

Tags: string, sed, awk

I'm having trouble with data manipulation in a txt file. My file currently looks like this:

```
    HG02239 -23.42333333
    NA06985NA06985  -20.125
    NA06991NA06991  -20.92
```

This shows some of my tab-delimited data. Half the entries are in the correct seven-characters (letterletternumbernumbernumbernumbernumber) format, but some are doubled up. I want to go into the second column (first column is empty for a reason!) and remove the repeats in the string so it would read

```
    HG02239 -23.42333333
    NA06985  -20.125
    NA06991  -20.92
```

I can't work out how to do this with sed/awk on a per column basis. I feel like I should be able to write a regex, but because the data is a repeat, I don't want to lose the first half of the string; and I can't work out how to cut on a specific column, or I would just delete the 7th character. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print substr($1, 1, 7), $2 }' file.txt
```

Output:

```
HG02239 -23.42333333
NA06985 -20.125
NA06991 -20.92
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

You can solve this with a backreference. For example, using GNU sed:

```
$ cat << EOF | sed --regexp-extended 's/(.{7})\1/\1/'
HG02239 -23.42333333
NA06985NA06985  -20.125
NA06991NA06991  -20.92
EOF

HG02239 -23.42333333
NA06985 -20.125
NA06991 -20.92
```

If you aren't using GNU sed, you may need to escape the capture groups. In addition, you can tune the regular expression if you need a more accurate character match.

#### Explanation

The cat pipeline is just a here-document to make it easy to display and test the code. You can call sed directly on your file, or use the **-i** flag to perform an in-place edit when you're comfortable with the results.

The sed script does the following:

1. It stores any group of 7 consecutive characters in a capture group using an "interval expression" (the number in the curly braces).
2. The `\1` is a backreference that matches the first capture group.
3. The match looks for "a capture group followed by a copy of the capture group."
4. The substitution replaces the match with a single copy of the capture group.

Comment: That works a treat! Could you take me through it so I can adapt it next time? /noob

Comment: The cat is Useless, you can use a here document with `sed` directly. See also http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
sed -i 's|\([A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{5\}\)[A-Z0-9]*\s*\(.*\)|\1 \2|g' <your-file>
```

Comment: That will match things that aren't duplicates, example `AB12345XYZ`